# This tag has been taken off [track]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

I just stumbled upon the [track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/track) tag.

It has no tag wiki or excerpt. At this moment, **299** questions are tagged with [track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/track). **162** of them are questions with no upvoted or accepted answers (close to 50%).

Uses vary quite a bit:

- [Video track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838790/show-subtitle-into-another-element)
- [Audio track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888362/spotify-audio-player-stops-randomly-after-few-seconds)
- [Tracking events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702027/track-javascript-event)
- [Tracking GPS positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683111/how-to-store-constantly-coordinates-in-a-db-and-then-update-replace-on-changes)
- [Tracking data usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617482/how-to-track-foreground-and-background-data-usage-for-each-app-in-android)
- [Tracking events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480645/how-to-track-weebly-form-submit-event-with-mixpanel)

Most of these are meant to be something like [tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tracking), which is marked *"DO NOT USE"*, but that's a whole separate burnination request.

Basically, [track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/track) is unclear, misused, and should be removed.

I can't think of a valid replacement tag, but make sure to add required tags where necessary and to **improve what needs improving**, should this burnination get started.

Comment: Score at the time of featuring is +75/–5.

Comment: ___Note:___ Please refrain from suggesting punny titles. As the [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) explains, chatty or punny comments will be removed. (The notifications I get for them aren't desired, either...)

Comment: Trogdor has been summoned; question has a score of +188/-7.

Comment: @CodyGray there are no open questions left

Comment: @VadimKotov I've left 6 questions there and deleted the rest. Those 6 seem like they've got some value in the answers and can remain on site. Check those once again and let me know.

Comment: @BhargavRao can they be retagged with more meaningful tags, to get rid of the [tag:track]?

Comment: Yep, @Vadim, that's fine. If any of them need to be reopened, ping me here with those, I'll reopen them and close this burnination.

Comment: @BhargavRao I've re-tagged the remaining questions. There are now 0 questions tagged `[track]`.

Comment: Cool, I've completed the burnination procedure. Do come up with a better pun if you can ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao: That's pretty much what I imagined when I saw the notification for that comment :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/track) has been *burninated*.

[image]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

---

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

There are various "tracking"-related tags that could be used instead, when retagging questions that are otherwise on-topic:

- [audiotrack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audiotrack) AudioTrack class in standard Android API for playing back raw Audio.
- [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) for questions about audio tracks
- [html5-audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-audio), [html5-video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-video) for questions about `track` element in HTML 5 Audio and Video.
- [bug-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug-tracking), [issue-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracking) for general bug tracking questions that aren't specific to a given tool.
- [trac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trac) for questions about Trac bug-tracking tool.
- [geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geolocation) for questions about assessing the location (e.g. GPS).
- [click-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click-tracking) (no wiki)
- [conversion-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conversion-tracking) (no wiki)
- [user-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-tracking) (no wiki)
- [event-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-tracking) used to collect data about interactions with your content (Google Analytics specific only)
- [eye-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eye-tracking) Is the specific task of detecting and tracking eyes over frames captured from a camera or video.
- [pitch-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pitch-tracking) the process of finding the dominant frequency of an audio signal
- [time-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-tracking) (No wiki)
- [video-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video-tracking)  Tracking a moving object or feature (e.g. a face) in video input.
- [motion-detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/motion-detection) detection of motion related to programming issues, like computer vision, sensor control, etc.
- [trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trace) for questions about execution of a process or method.

---

## Progress:

The [track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/track) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=track),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btrack%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btrack%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btrack%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btrack%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/track) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/track) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a defence, but note that in regard to location systems, track or tracking has a specific meaning, i.e. remotely monitoring the trajectory of a person, vehicle or object.

In regard to video and audio tracks, this again has a specific meaning, i.e the physical markings that are used to store the information.

The other uses of tracking cited above e.g. 'tracking events' are more a generic monitoring.  Accordingly, replacement tracks could be 'video-track', 'audio-track','location-track', and then discourage use of tags for the more generic monitoring.

Comment: And are those meaning relevant in a specific programming context where others tags would never be applicable?